# Rails 3. Writing ActiveRecord queries with raw SQL or Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I am looking through a legacy codebase and I see something like this:

```
def all_story_links
    StoryLink.complete.where("
      (storyable_type = 'Recipe' AND storyable_id = ?)
      OR
      (storyable_type = 'RecipeStep' AND storyable_id IN (?))
      OR
      (storyable_type = 'RecipeIngredient' AND storyable_id IN (?)
      )", id, recipe_step_ids, recipe_ingredient_ids)
  end
```

What is that called inside the where method? What is it? Is it AREL? Does this exist because there is no ActiveRecord convenience methods that resolves to this? is it SQL or Arel? Got any good resources to learn AREL quickly?

Comment: "What is that called inside the where method?" -> An SQL query...? And no, this is not using the arel wrapper. Asking for tutorials is not on-topic on Stack Overflow. Sorry :-( The [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are quite good though, and should provide you with most of the basic information to get started.

Answer (score 0):

What's inside the **where** method is mostly plain old SQL, with the added feature of Rails doing substitutions wherever it sees the question marks ("?"). Rails substitutes for the question marks, the values given to the **where** method after the query itself: **id, recipe_step_ids....**.

It is not AREL.

The plain old SQL was probably used in this case because the ANDs and ORs would have been difficult or impossible to implement using the ActiveRecord API.